# Issue to play a mp3 file with a Python script from Arduino data

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I am trying to perform the following action with an Arduino Uno and a Python script: if the length calculated by the ultrawave sensor of Arduino is below 36 then play a music which is on my hard drive.

My Python code is the following one:

```
import serial, webbrowser

arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
data = arduino.readline()

while (1==1):
    if (arduino.inWaiting()>0) and data < 36:
        webbrowser.open("/home/path/my-music.mp3")
```

But nothing is happening when I am launching it, the script kept running in my shell.
If I perform a print data I noticed that the value of data is different from the Arduino console and it seems that the Arduino console is not working properly (the length value of the ultrawave sensor seem truncated) when the Python script is running at the same time.

when I run the following Python script:

```
import serial, webbrowser
webbrowser.open("/home/path/my-music.mp3")
```

My mp3 is played properly.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your script to tell you what is happening. I can not test it out.

```
# import the modules
import serial
import webbrowser

# open a serial connection to the Arduino to read data from
arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

# we want to read everything the Arduino tells us
while True:

    # read one line (a str) that the Arduino wrote with Serial.println()
    line = arduino.readline()

    # convert the line into a string that contains only the numbers
    # by stripping away the line break characters and spaces
    string_with_number_in_it = line.strip()

    # convert the string into a number that can be compared
    number = float(string_with_number_in_it)

    if number < 36:
        webbrowser.open("/home/path/my-music.mp3")
```

Also, I suggest you install [mplayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPlayer) and use it instead of the webbrowser.

```
import subprocess
def play_music_file(filename):
    subprocess.call(('mplayer', filename))
```

Comment: Thanks to you it works :). I just got an additionnal issue due to the Arduino consolo which was a bit slow, but I fixed it adding a delay to it. Thanks to you I could finished my tutorial, it is in French but better than nothing : http://ronan-chardonneau.fr/arduino-exemple-dune-collecte-de-donnees-qui-va-declencher-une-action/

Comment: Cool, you can mark the answer as accepted and refer to it on the website if you like. Thanks for letting me know!